# Is there a way to find the equivalent command line calls Kitematic uses when interacting with docker?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, kitematic

I’m new to docker and am using docker for windows. I’m also using Kitematic to pull repository images, configure the container, start, restart, set ports, etc.

Is there a way to find out exactly what commands Kitematic is sending to docker so I can learn what it is doing?

Comment: You can take a look to source code ;) ^^

Comment: Is that supposed to be helpful?

Comment: You can take a look to the docker documentation to see which commands are used for those actions. But describing all commands in docker is a lot of work.

Comment: I’m reading the docs, but what I’d like to see is when I hit “create” in Kitematic, is a console or some such.  Maybe another GUI has one